# How to use Lagrange interpolation method for station lies between a grid?

Tags: interpolation, gis-principle, precipitation

[image]

I have rainfall data for a catchment from 1990-2020 in grid format. But my station of interests lies in the grid, how to apply the interpolation to that station. I'm not sure if I'm proceeding correctly, firstly I considered horizontal direction where I applied interpolation based on the distance.  Then followed vertical direction.  I'm I following the right direction?

Comment: Kindly mention the software or programming language you are using.

Comment: Presently using Excel